How to execute kubectl commands in HCP?
I have very simple use case that I am trying to run kubectl command using terraform's HCP
resource "null_resource" "meta_create_namespace_and_secret" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl create namespace meta && kubectl create secret generic minio -n meta --from-literal=rootUser=jk_infra --from-literal=rootPassword=ab3c2#DcejC"]."
  }

  # adding static trigger to run this only once 
  triggers = {
    always_run = "true"
  }
}

I get the following errors
Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "kubectl create namespace meta && kubectl create secret generic minio -n meta --from-literal=rootUser=jk_infra --from-literal=rootPassword=ab3c2#DcejC"].  //not in use
  /bin/sh: 1: kubectl: not found

I know I can do it using kubectl manifest provider but is there a way to do it using just commands ?

local exec commands run on your machine, so you'll need to have kubectl installed for that to work. you shouldn't need to use local exec for this, why can't you use proper terraform resources?

FYI this question seems to have disclosed a username and password. I mention it just in case that was a live password that you would now want to rotate.

It wasn't a live password just a test password which is also not in use

kubectl is not installed on HashiCorp Cloud Platform by default and it can be added by terraform with the help of null_resource or terraform_data which the later one is preferred.
resource "terraform_data" "meta_create_namespace_and_secret" {

  # trigger each time
  triggers_replace = [
    "${timestamp()}"
  ]

  # download kubectl
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl create namespace meta && kubectl create secret generic minio -n meta --from-literal=rootUser=ck_infra_admin --from-literal=rootPassword=f23ff2#DcejC:d"
  }

}

or
resource "null_resource" "meta_create_namespace_and_secret" {

  # download kubectl
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl create namespace meta && kubectl create secret generic minio -n meta --from-literal=rootUser=ck_infra_admin --from-literal=rootPassword=f23ff2#DcejC:d"
  }

  # adding static trigger to run this only once 
  triggers = {
    always_run = "true"
  }
}


I can show you 2 methods in order to create kubernetes components using terraform
1st method:
you can use this provider
kubectl terraform provider
You need add this block to your providers.tf file
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubectl = {
      source = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "1.16.0"
    }
  }
}

// you need to configure the kubectl provider section in order to enable terraform to authenticate to your cluster

provider "kubectl" {
  host                   = 
  cluster_ca_certificate = 
  token                  = 
}

After configuring the provider you just need to create a file named for example secret.yml
For example we going to fill it with:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-sa
  namespace: test
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
data:
  extra: YmFyCg==

In order to deploy to secret.yml file you just need to add file name secret.tf that contain
resource "kubectl_manifest" "dapr_secret" {
  yaml_body = file("./secret.yml")
}

Finaly run:
terraform apply

2nd method:
you can use this provider
kubernetes terraform provider
You need to add this block to your providers.tf file
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.34.0"
    }
  }
}

// you need to configure the kubernetes provider section in order to enable terraform to authenticate to your cluster

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = 
  cluster_ca_certificate = 
  token                  = 
}

Create a file named secret.tf and copy this config
In case your wondering where did I found this config
resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" { 
  metadata {
    name = "secret-sa"
    namespace ="test"
  }
  data = {
    "extra" = "base64secret"
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
}

In case your wondering where did I found this config
Kubernetes secret terraform
